# How to get data from url and pass it to block method

Tags: magento-1.8, controllers, blocks

I need to get data from url and pass it block method for some operation.
Basically i need to list some content on specific id in magento.

```
my controller function is
----------------------------

        public function showArchiveAction() {

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParams('o');
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();
          }

my block method
----------------
public function getMagazine($id)
     {

      $defaultMagazine = Mage::getModel('magazine/display')->getCollection()->load($id);
      $data = $defaultMagazine->getData();
      $defaultMagazineId = $data[0]['magazine_id'];
      $collection = Mage::getModel('magazine/page')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('magazine_id',$defaultMagazineId);

      return $collection;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like you are getting the id right.
You have 2 options here to send the data to the block.
**Option 1** - Using `register`.

```
public function showArchiveAction() {
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParams('o');
    Mage::register('current_magazine_id', $id);//register the id
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Then you can read the id in the block or the template:

```
$id = Mage::registry('current_magazine_id');
$magazine = $this->getMagazine($id);
```

**Option 2** - assigning the id to the block.
For this approach let's say that you block has the name `magazine_details` in the layout.

```
public function showArchiveAction() {
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParams('o');
    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('magazine_details');
    if ($block) {
         $block->setMagazineId($id);
    }
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Then you can read this value in the block or template like this:

```
$id = $this->getMagazineId();
$magazine = $this->getMagazine($id);
```

Comment: This means that there is no block with that name. You should take the first approach. It's easier

Comment: I don't really understand you new question. But please keep this website clean. Ask an other question and explain in details what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I extended my question...pls read...

Comment: I edited my question...can u read again

Comment: I read it. But I don't understand what you mean. Like I said. PLease keep things separate. Don't put 2 questions in one.